# Custom post type & role issues

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, user-roles

I am having issues with using custom post types and custom user roles. I created a custom post type called Businesses. Then I created capabilities for users of a certain type to be able to add and edit business listings. The problem I am having is when I create the user type and add the capabilities of edit_business, edit_businesses, read_business, publish_businesses, the user has the ability to edit other peoples businesses. I can't figure out why this is happening.

A snippet of the code I used to create the capabilities is `'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_post' => 'edit_business',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_business',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_businesses',
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_businesses',
            'read_post' => 'read_business',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_businesses',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_business'
        )`

Any help understanding this would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please post in full registration code for your CPT and user role? This doesn't seem enough to make a guess what is broken to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem here. When you use the members plugin and create roles for custom post types you need to create a function which maps out your meta capabilities. http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types